# error al invocar funciones de JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, formularios, eventos

al invocar la función `ChooseForm()` se invoca otra función(`funcverif()`) que lo que permite la segunda función es cambiar las propiedades de un botón o hacerlo aparecer mediante css, pero cuando se ejecuta todo, la pagina se recarga y vuelve a su estado inicial.

como podría mejorar el código para que esto no suceda?

```js
function ChooseForm() {
  return funcverif();
}
// ---------------------------------------

function funcverif() {
  document.getElementById('btnVERIF').style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('btnVERIF').style.display = 'initial';
}
```

```css
a {
  margin-left: 140px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#table_1 {
  margin: 50px 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#table_1 tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 120px;
  width: 475px;
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

textarea {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 430px;
  height: 150px;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}


#btnVERIF{
 visibility: hidden;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <table id="table_1">
      <tr>
        <th>Stolem1</th>
        <th>Stolem2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form action="">
            <label>User: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="form1_US" placeholder="Nickname" id="userForm"><br><br>
            <label> Password:</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="form1_PASS" placeholder="password" id="PasswordForm"><br><br>
            <label> Seleccione una:</label><br>
            <button id="btnVERIF" onclick="funcverif()">VERIFICAR</button><br><br>
            <button id="btnInvoc" onclick="ChooseForm()">VERIFICAR DATOS</button>

            </select>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La recarga se te produce porque se está enviando el formulario al hacer *click* en el botón `#btnInvoc` debido a que por defecto, si no le asignamos un tipo a un botón, este es `type="submit"`.

Especificando que el botón sea `type="button"` solucionarías el problema.

```js
function ChooseForm() {
  return funcverif();
}
// ---------------------------------------

function funcverif() {
  document.getElementById('btnVERIF').style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('btnVERIF').style.display = 'initial';
}
```

```css
a {
  margin-left: 140px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#table_1 {
  margin: 50px 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#table_1 tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 120px;
  width: 475px;
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

textarea {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 430px;
  height: 150px;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}


#btnVERIF{
 visibility: hidden;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <table id="table_1">
      <tr>
        <th>Stolem1</th>
        <th>Stolem2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form action="">
            <label>User: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="form1_US" placeholder="Nickname" id="userForm"><br><br>
            <label> Password:</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="form1_PASS" placeholder="password" id="PasswordForm"><br><br>
            <label> Seleccione una:</label><br>
            <button id="btnVERIF" onclick="funcverif()">VERIFICAR</button><br><br>
            <button type="button" id="btnInvoc" onclick="ChooseForm()">VERIFICAR DATOS</button>

            </select>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
```